# Problems adding an article in Joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, article

I got a problem I really cant solve. I am trying to create a menu with an single article in Joomla 2.5, but it wont show the article.
I have created a main menu with some menus which are set to **single article**, and I have created some articles, which I've added to the specific menu items, it has no problems saving the menu, but when I reload the page, there is no article/text/picture.

Does some one have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Have you fiddled with any of the core Joomla code or the database tables? Can you provide a link to your website please?

Comment: I havent looked in to any core Joomla code or the database :S 
Here is the [website](http://test1.helbografisk.dk)

Comment: If you use the search function, you can easly search for the content in the article, but when u click on it, it wont apear. Try entering "fodbold" (its in danish)

Comment: I have a strange feeling it might have something to do with your template. Try setting the template to the default Joomla template (Beez20) and see if the article is shown.

Comment: sadly i think you are right.. I have tryed changing it, and the other template shows my articles..

Comment: Okay, i have fixed the problem. Apparently the setting in my template showing system output was set to "no".
But any ways, thank you for your efforts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem. Under my profil for the template, "System Output" whas set to "no". Changed it to "yes" and it shows all my article.

But thanks for your efforts

Answer (score 0):

Make sure article is published. Even if it won't work. Just on error reporting n see what exactly error is getting about & find the solution.

Comment: The article is published, but i cant seem to find the error :s

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a SEF issue.

Say your menu is published under the SEF url /fun/jokes.html: if the SEF plugin is not enabled Joomla might be looking for your pictures in **/fun/images/...** instead of /images/...

Just head to the administrator / plugin, search for SEF (system - SEF plugin) and enable it.
Clear the cache and it should start working.